# how to get only current date

Tags: c#

i have 3 dropdownlist for dd,mm,yyyy.
how to restrict user to enter date greater than current date. ex 7 may 2015.
while giving input  7 may 2015 its giving invalid date. how to restrict user not to select dropdown item greater than current date

```
 protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
            string dayNumber = date1.ToString("dd",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            string MonthNumber = date1.ToString("MM",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            string YearNumber = date1.ToString("yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (DDLDay.SelectedItem.Text != "DD" && DDLMonth.SelectedItem.Text != "MM" && DDLYear.SelectedItem.Text != "YYYY")
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(DDLYear.SelectedItem.Text) <= Convert.ToInt32(YearNumber))
                {
                    if ((Convert.ToInt32(DDLMonth.SelectedItem.Value) <= Convert.ToInt32(MonthNumber)))
                    {

                        if ((Convert.ToInt32(DDLMonth.SelectedItem.Value) <= Convert.ToInt32(MonthNumber)))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Response.Write("not valid day ");
                            return;
                        }
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("not valid day");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    Response.Write("not valid day ");
                    return;
                }


            }

            else
            {
                Response.Write("DOB Cannot blank");
            }




        }



  string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

Comment: `bool valid = date >= DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 2):

From your current code, you can easily construct a `DateTime` object and compare that:

```
DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime( Convert.ToInt32(YearNumber)
                                    , Convert.ToInt32(MonthNumber)
                                    , Convert.ToInt32(DayNumber)
                                    );

if (selectedDate > DateTime.Now)
{
    // error
}
```

You could use the built-in `input type="date"` in order to have a uniform way the date is formatted. It also supports a maximum date to select.

Answer (score 2):

Why not straighforward `>` (or `>=`) between two dates (`userInput` and `limit`):

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DateTime limit = DateTime.Now.Date;  

  DateTime userInput = new DateTime(
    int.Parse(DDLYear.SelectedItem.Text),
    int.Parse(DDLMonth.SelectedItem.Text), 
    int.Parse(DDLDay.SelectedItem.Text));  

  //TODO: it's unclear from the question if you want ">" or ">=", put right comparison
  if (userInput >= limit)  {
    Response.Write("not valid day ");

    return;
  }

  ...
}
```